# How to remove the SSL_Certificate error while making API calls

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate, here-api, heremaps

I am making API calls from my machine to HERE maps. I am getting an error from Pythons request library that SSL Certificate verification failed. IT works when I set verify = False.
Does it has something to do with firewall or something ??

Comment: Not necessarily. The error just means that the verification did not pass. Might just be a faulty SSL cert, or a bug in requests.

Comment: How exactly to identify that SSL cert is faulty ??

Comment: Hi Ravi, could you share a bit more info? Like What service did you call and how did you do that?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Yes , I am calling the Here Maps Routing API and Traffic API from python using "GET" method. The call works fine in my local windows machine but I have some Linux machines which are throwing this error.

Comment: @Ravi, it would be perfect if you could provide code snippet so we can help with it. Thanks (We tested service itself but no suspicious found.)

Comment: Hi Ravi, Could you please provide the requested details.?